# MVC3 custom server-side data annotation validation not working in partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations, partial-views, custom-attributes

I am trying to add custom data validation via data annotations.  I am only concerned about server-side validation at this point.  Everything I have seen here and elsewhere references client-side validation.  I've stripped down all my code, ran a few test cases and I can get this working just fine on a regular view but as soon as the form is in a partial view, the code no longer breaks in the method to override IsValid.

In either case I can see the custom attribute being initialized.  When the form is in a regular view I can see the override method being executed upon submitting the form, but when in a partial view the code never gets executed and it goes right to the HttpPost action.

I have spent the better parts of two days trying to figure this out and am at a loss.  Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Note:
The code below does return the same view when it enters the HttpPost action.  I have it like this for testing purposes.  I know my override is never getting called from the partial view and thus IsValid is always true.

View showing form where the validation works

```
@model eRecruitBoard.ViewModels.HomeIndexViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "eRecruitBoard";
}
@*<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>*@

<h2>Login/homepage</h2>

<br /><br />
 <div class="errorMessage">
 @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.LoginErrorMsg)
</div>
<br />

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home")) {
    <div id="loginControlBox">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Welcome to eRecruitBoard</legend> 

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Date)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Date)
            </div>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Log In" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
}
    <div>
        @Html.Action("BlankForm", "TestForm")
    </div>
```

Partial View (these script calls also come in via _Layout, but I had them here for testing as well)

```
@model eRecruitBoard.ViewModels.TestFormViewModel

    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>    
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcValidation.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("NewActivity2", "TestForm", FormMethod.Post))
{
<fieldset>
    <legend>Test Form</legend>
    <br />
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Date)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Date)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Date)
    <input id="activityTimelineSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</fieldset>
}
```

ViewModel (for partial view)

```
namespace eRecruitBoard.ViewModels
{
    public class TestFormViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
        [NonFutureDate()]
        [Display(Name = "Date")]
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller (for partial view)

```
namespace eRecruitBoard.Controllers
{
    public class TestFormController :BaseController
    {
        public ActionResult BlankForm()
        {
            var viewModel = new TestFormViewModel
            {
                Date = DateTime.Today
            };

            return PartialView("_TestForm", viewModel);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult NewActivity2(DateTime Date)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            else
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
    }
}
```

Validation code

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace eRecruitBoard.WebLibrary.Validation
{
    [AttributeUsageAttribute(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Parameter, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
    public class NonFutureDateAttribute : ValidationAttribute  //public sealed class 
    {
        public NonFutureDateAttribute(): base("Activity can only be saved for today or dates in the past.")
        {
        }
        public override bool IsValid(object value)
        {
            DateTime dateToCheck = (DateTime)value;
            return (dateToCheck <= DateTime.Today);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you `RedirectToAction` you lose all validation. You have to `return PartialView(model)` in your POST action. That would require changing the parameter type of `NewActivity2` to `TestFormViewModel` instead of `DateTime`.

Update your code with example of how you display the partial view (`@Html.Partial()` or javascript) if it still doesnt work.